# Need for diaphragm carburetors in small internal combustion engines that run on gasoline

Tags: mechanical-engineering, engines, combustion, carburetor

I have seen that hobby internal combustion engines that run on gasoline always use diaphragm carburetors instead of the very simple carburation system used by glow engines that generally consist only of a venturi and a needle valve. Why is the need to add all the complexity of these  diaphragm carburetors, that generally consist of fuel pump, metering system and several valves? Why does the basic principle of the glow system in which the vacuum created by the piston pulls the correct fuel/air mix fails when gasoline is used?

Comment: Random guess, glow plugs running on glow fuel are far more tolerant of mixture variation than spark plugs running on gasoline.